# Finding and Removing Unused Files Through Command Line

Tags: shell, search, command-line, ssh, command

My websites file structure has gotten very messy over the years from uploading random files to test different things out.  I have a list of all my files such as this:

```
file1.html
another.html
otherstuff.php
cool.jpg
whatsthisdo.js
hmmmm.js
```

Is there any way I can input my list of files via command line and search the contents of all the other files on my website and output a list of the files that aren't mentioned anywhere on my other files?

For example, if cool.jpg and hmmmm.js weren't mentioned in any of my other files then it could output them in a list like this:

```
cool.jpg
hmmmm.js
```

And then any of those other files mentioned above aren't listed because they are mentioned somewhere in another file.  Note:  I don't want it to just automatically delete the unused files, I'll do that manually.

Also, of course I have multiple folders so it will need to search recursively from my current location and output all the unused (unreferenced) files.

I'm thinking command line would be the fastest/easiest way, unless someone knows of another.  Thanks in advance for any help that you guys can be!

Answer (score 1):

Yep! This is pretty easy to do with `grep`. In this case, you would run a command like:

```
$ for orphan in `cat orphans.txt`; do \
    echo "Checking for presence of ${orphan} in present directory..." ;
    grep -rl $orphan . ; done
```

And orphans.txt would look like your list of files above, one file per line. You can add `-i` to the `grep` above if you want to grep case-insensitively. And you would want to run that command in `/var/www` or wherever your distribution keeps its webroots. If, after you see the above "Checking for..." and no matches below, you haven't got any files matching that name.